# What server should I setup to use Mule SFTP Endpoint

Tags: mule, sftp

I am very new to SFTP endpoint in mule. I am trying implement a sample example using SFTP endpoint.

I have used FTP endpoint and it worked fine with (FileZilla Server version 0.9.43 beta). Does the same FillZilla server work for SFTP endpoint or should I install some other Server?

When I use this FileZilla server I am always getting Connection refused exception
`java.io.IOException: Error during login to wsl@localhost: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect`

Can any one please tell me what server exactly I have to install to use SFTP endpoint and direct me to sample SFTP example documentation.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FileZilla server does not support SFTP, so you will need another server. See a list of FTP server comparisons here, and select one with SFTP support:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_FTP_server_software

Comment: Thanks Anton for responding, now I am using Crush FTP server. I have downloaded and started server. When I run my mule application on mule studio, still I am getting the same "Connection refused: connect" exception

Comment: Try to connect with FileZilla, WinSCP or some other SFTP client to debug. I don't think this problem is Mule-related.

Comment: Thanks Anton, it worked to me. Basically, default ssh port is 2222 in Crush FTP server. I have created a new user and few directories with all permissions for that user.

Answer (score 0):

If you are only trying things out, you could use a mock SFTP server. Check the SFTP transports:

https://github.com/mulesoft/mule/blob/mule-3.x/transports/sftp/src/test/java/org/mule/transport/sftp/AbstractSftpFunctionalTestCase.java

Comment: No Seba, I want make it work on my side with a FTP server. Now I am using Crush FTP server which supports SFTP. I have configured sftp connector in mule studio with following details. 
host:localhost
port : 22
path :
username:crushadmin
password:admin

But, still I am getting the same error "Connection refused: connect"

Comment: I have tried also with '8080' default port of CrushFTP server. But, no luck for me. Please suggest me a ftp server which I can be able work with SFTP endpoint in mule.

Comment: Hi Seba, Problem solved. Thanks for your response. ssh default port is 2222 in crush ftp server.

Answer (score 0):

If you are testing you can check out the SFTP server of the Munit

https://github.com/mulesoft/munit/wiki/ftp-server

You can also check the code to see how we did it